# How to find XOR of three numbers taken input from the user in java

Tags: java

How to calculate the XOR of three numbers for example numbers input from the user are a,b and c 
then (a XOR b XOR) = ?

I wrote a function to calculate the same, but it is not working properly  :

```
int xorsum(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        int res1 = (a|b)& (~a|~b);
        int res = (res1|c) & (~res1 | ~c);
        return res ;
    }
```

Comment: There is  the `^` operator for XOR...

Comment: you mean `int xorsum(int a, int b, int c) {
    return (a ^ b) ^ c;
}`

Comment: Not working properly?? Why? It is producing the correct output. What do you expect as output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int xorsum(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return (a ^ b) ^ c;
    }
```

Explication:

XOR is defined as a binary operator (i.e. with two arguments), and not as a function of more than two variables.
A XOR B XOR C = (A XOR B) XOR C = A XOR (B XOR C)

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.